# I get site blocking and captcha when using Python Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, captcha

when I try to enter the site (https://www.ticketcorner.ch/en/artist/iihf-eishockey-weltmeisterschaft/2020-iihf-ice-hockey-world-championship-einzelspiel-tickets-zuerich-2463148/?affiliate=IIH)using Selenium webdriver, I get captcha or blocking page.
Are there any ways to get around this without using captcha recognition services?
Thank you.

UPD. Attached captcha img
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXa4f.jpg)

```
import time


from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main():
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
    driver.get('https://www.ticketcorner.ch/en/artist/iihf-eishockey-weltmeisterschaft/2020-iihf-ice-hockey-world-championship-einzelspiel-tickets-zuerich-2463148/?affiliate=IIH')
    while True:
        time.sleep(3)
        driver.refresh()
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h2[@class="event-listing-city theme-headline-color"]')))
            source = driver.page_source

            soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
            elements = soup.find_all('h2', class_='event-listing-city theme-headline-color')
            matches = []
            for elem in elements:
                matches.append(elem.text)
            print(matches)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Parsing error', str(e))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What type of captcha is it? If it is a simple click one they there are ways around it. But if it is a "Click the images" then it becomes a lot more complex. But there isn't a way to avoid it completly. Captcha were created to stop scrapers like this one.

Comment: Yes, this is a captcha with images. Maybe there are some ways to emulate human behavior, js requests, and other?